# Jquery ui datepicker year scrollbar fails to visually update when dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, scrollbar

The datepicker year selector scroll thumb is frozen, does not visually drag.  When I release the mouse, the year has changed in the input field. If I click the dropdown selector again, that year is highlighted.

The thumb does not flicker on mousedown, but does flicker when I first start to drag.
On mouseup, the dropdown closes.
The year that gets selected is right around where the mouse pointer was in the scroll bar.

(Using jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js, datepicker version: "1.10.3", jquery v1.9.1)

I've tried the following combinations of attributes:

```
            dateField.datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+100",
            dateFormat: primaryDateFormat,
            onSelect: function() { dateField.blur(); }
        }); 

            dateField.datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1900:2100",
            dateFormat: primaryDateFormat,
            onSelect: function() { dateField.blur(); }
        }); 
            dateField.datepicker({
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1900:2100",
            dateFormat: primaryDateFormat,
            onSelect: function() { dateField.blur(); }
        });
```

For these settings, the thumb and scrollbar show, and the thumb is the full height of the dropdown selector.  It flickers on mouse drag.

```
            dateField.datepicker({
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: primaryDateFormat,  
            dateFormat: primaryDateFormat,
            onSelect: function() { dateField.blur(); }
        });
```

Any suggestions on troubleshooting or workarounds is greatly appreciated.  I don't know what to do next except debug the jquery events.

Also, clicking on a date from the dropdown works, and using the keyboard up/down arrows provides navigation for the whole range.
One other behavior I noticed is that when the dropdown is displayed, a mouse hover over the first year highlights the year, and dragging the mouse down highlights each year except the last one.
For example, if the years are 1920-1930, I hover the mouse over 1920 and it's highlighted, I drag down the list and hover over 1930.  1930 is not highlighted, but 1929 is.

The problem is reproduced here - http://jsfiddle.net/AnneG/MGe5G/8/

Thanks very much,

Anne

Comment: Did you try from a different browser? The way different browsers render this 'glitch' might give you a hint to what is happening. Maybe you have some css overriding the jquery UI css.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I also tried it from IE 10.  I just got the jsfiddle example working, and the problem shows up there, too.

Comment: I just found this, so I guess it's game over: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9769

Comment: Ouch! Well just so you know, you can either delete your question or answer it yourself and mark as answered. Cheers.

Comment: I'm just lucky...Fixed as of Chrome v32.0.1700.107 m.  I just had to update my browser version.  I can't answer my own question for 8 hours, so I'll mark it answered tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed as of Chrome v32.0.1700.107 m. I just had to update my browser to this version.

Background: 
Known bug, Chrome related: 
JQuery-UI cannot fix it from their end: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9769 
Chrome Issue log - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334522) - marked fixed in v32.0.1700.76 m, 34.0.1785.0 canary